# Security about creating a server on client side on the fly

Tags: security, networking, ip, game-development

I have a security question about games and network.

Today most games (like Call of Duty) uses a 'on client side host' server system. So for some time, one client becomes the host of the game. I'm looking for some resources on how to do this properly (in a technical and safe way) because I'm working on a project like that.
But for now the only solution I found is to share the IP address of my host clients to other guest clients. And I'm not proud of this. So I am looking for a method or technology like IP masking or another stuff like that would protect my customers from other malicious customers that could retrieve IP of my customers and maybe hack them?

**EDIT:**
But what I'm asking is if there is any solution like services like on the fly subdomains redirections with parameters for connecting to specific clients or anything like that? I mean
`subdomain.mygame.com/clientname`

Answer (score 1):

If you want true peer-to-peer connections in your game there is no way around sharing the IP address. After all if they are to talk with one another then they need to know how to reach the others.

Alternatively you can route all their traffic through your server and each client connects to it independently. That way they do not have to know any information about each other except your in-game user id.

Comment: hm.. I don't really do peer to peer, but yes I want to protect my customers like p2p do. I thought about your second solution but that method increase the latency and that's not really good for a gaming project. This generate more lags. I edited the first post.

Comment: No, these would all only be abstractions *on top* of the low level network protocol that *needs* to have an IP address to sent IP packages. If latency is a problem then the best you can do is put the proxy server closer to your users ("close" referring to network topology).

Comment: Yes, but a proxy has the same problem of the alternative solution. So I guess there is not really an ideal solution to my problem. So maybe I can do a hybrid solution? Let the possibility to gamers to be a host by explicitely check this option and warning their IP would be shared to other clients. Or use the alternative solution where they will connect to a main server where the latency could be higher.

Comment: Yes. But how do the AAA games like call of duty. Do you think that guest clients are connecting to host clients? If yes, I guess this is hidden by the game UI but I mean in background of the game.